# Syntax Error for variable name

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting an unexpected syntax error

```
   total = homework + quizzes + tests
    ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have absolutely no idea why that line is in error. Furthermore, and I'm very curious about this, my text editor (Sublime 2) leaves variable names unchanged in color, however when I type the line `total = homework + quizzes + tests` total is highlighted in orange which is a color generally reserved for function arguments. I'm hoping somebody can elucidate this situation.

```
def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student("homework")) * .1
    quizzes = average(student("quizzes")) * .3
    tests = average(student(("tests")) * .6
    total = homework + quizzes + tests
    return total
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bracket mismatch on the previous line, due to which Python continues parsing into the next line, and hence throws the error in the next line.

To correct this, use:

```
tests = average(student("tests")) * .6
```

Instead of:

```
tests = average(student(("tests")) * .6
```